# Fail to create bean in spring suddently

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6

I have encountered a problem of failed to create bean in spring suddenly. The webapp is already deployed and has been running for several months. However, below error message comes suddenly. It can be resolved by restarting the webapp, but comes again without any hints. Does anyone have any idea of this case?

Tomcat 6 is being used to host the webapp.

```
[2013/05/03 12:02:56:421 HKT] ajp-8009-42 org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter(227) - Exception in the filter chain
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error creating bean with name 'reportGenerationBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'scheduleBean' while setting bean property 'scheduleBean'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduleBean': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

applicationContext.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:webapp.properties,classpath*:env_prod.properties"/>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="facesUtils" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticMethod">
            <value>com.webapp.util.FacesUtils.init</value>
        </property>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>com.webapp.config.SpringBeanEnum</value>
                <value>com.webapp.config.FacesBeanEnum</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory"><ref local="inspectbookSessionFactory"/></property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.webapp.bo, com.webapp.service" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="hibernateDAO" abstract="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory"><ref local="inspectbookSessionFactory"/></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Temporary Setting -->
    <bean id="ItemSearchBeanDao" class="com.webapp.dao.tmp.ItemSearchBeanDao" parent="hibernateDAO">
        <property name="maxRecordNo" value="${no_of_record.order}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="BookedSearchBeanDao" class="com.webapp.dao.tmp.BookedSearchBeanDao" parent="hibernateDAO">
        <property name="maxRecordNo" value="${no_of_record.booked}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ScheduleBeanDao" class="com.webapp.dao.tmp.ScheduleBeanDao" parent="hibernateDAO"></bean>
    <bean id="WhItemSearchBeanDao" class="com.webapp.dao.tmp.WhItemSearchBeanDao" parent="hibernateDAO">
        <property name="maxRecordNo" value="${no_of_record.whItem}"/>
    </bean>




    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="-secret-"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="EmailUtil" class="com.webapp.util.EmailUtil">
      <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="freeMarkerTemplateMailer" class="com.webapp.bo.email.impl.FreeMarkerTemplateMailer">
      <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emailService" class="com.webapp.bo.email.impl.EmailServiceImpl" >
        <property name="orgunitDao" ref="OrgunitDAO"/>
        <property name="contactMethodDao" ref="ContactMethodDAO"/>
        <property name="mailer" ref="freeMarkerTemplateMailer"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduleEmail" class="com.webapp.bo.schedule.impl.ScheduleEmailImpl" >
        <property name="orgunitDao" ref="OrgunitDAO"/>
        <property name="scheduleBeanDao" ref="ScheduleBeanDao"/>
        <property name="emailService" ref="emailService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="scheduleJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.webapp.service.schedule.ScheduleJob" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="scheduleEmail" value-ref="scheduleEmail" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean> 



<!-- JSF backing bean START -->
    <bean id="vendorSearchBean" class="com.webapp.service.search.item.VendorSearchBean" scope="session">
        <property name="maxRecordNo" value="${no_of_record.vendor}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemSearchBean" name="itemSearchBean" class="com.webapp.service.search.item.NewItemSearchBean" scope="session">
        <property name="maxRecordNo" value="${no_of_record.order}"/>
        <property name="popupBean" ref="popupBean"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemSearchPopupBean" name="itemSearchPopupBean" class="com.webapp.service.search.item.NewItemSearchBean" scope="session">
        <property name="maxRecordNo" value="${no_of_record.order}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="detailBean" class="com.webapp.service.detail.DetailBean" scope="session">
        <property name="itemSearchBean" ref="itemSearchBean"/>
        <property name="itemSearchPopupBean" ref="itemSearchPopupBean"/>
        <property name="popupBean" ref="popupBean"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="bookedSearchBean" class="com.webapp.service.search.booked.BookedSearchBean" scope="session">
        <property name="maxRecordNo" value="${no_of_record.booked}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduleConfirmBean" class="com.webapp.service.schedule.ScheduleConfirmBean" scope="session">
        <property name="popupBean" ref="popupBean"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduleBean" class="com.webapp.service.search.schedule.ScheduleBean" scope="session">
        <property name="popupBean" ref="popupBean"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dropBean" class="com.webapp.service.search.schedule.DropBean" scope="request">
        <property name="scheduleBean" ref="scheduleBean"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="inspectContactBean" class="com.webapp.service.detail.contact.InspectContactBean" scope="session">
        <property name="detailBean" ref="detailBean"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="inspectLocationBean" class="com.webapp.service.detail.contact.InspectLocationBean" scope="session">
        <property name="detailBean" ref="detailBean"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="whItemSearchBean" class="com.webapp.service.search.warehouse.WhItemSearchBean" scope="session">
        <property name="maxRecordNo" value="${no_of_record.whItem}"/>
        <!--<property name="propertiesUtil" ref="propertiesUtil"/>-->
    </bean>

    <!-- Autocomplete -->
    <bean id="autocomplete" class="com.webapp.service.common.AutocompleteBean" scope="session"></bean>

    <!-- PackingListBean -->
    <bean id="packingListBean" class="com.webapp.service.common.PackingListBean" scope="session">
        <property name="itemSearchBean" ref="itemSearchBean"/>
        <property name="popupBean" ref="popupBean"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Report Bean -->
    <bean id="reportGenerationBean" class="com.webapp.service.report.ReportGenerationBean" scope="request">
        <property name="itemSearchBean" ref="itemSearchBean"/>
        <property name="packingListBean" ref="packingListBean"/>
        <property name="scheduleBean" ref="scheduleBean"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- popupBean -->
    <bean id="popupBean" class="com.webapp.service.common.PopupControlBean" scope="session">
    </bean>

<!-- JSF backing bean  END  -->  

</beans>
```

Comment: There seem to be some configuration mismatch in your applicationContext.xml. Please post the same..

Comment: Is there any possibility that the given exception happens during constructo call to you `scheduleBean`?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of scheduleBean class: constructor, any @PostConstruct methods, anything that is autowired, etc.

Comment: Consider sharing the bean definition and the "scheduleBean" property class code which it points to.

Comment: applicationContext.xml is posted ~~~

Comment: The strange point is system ran normally several months, but the exception happened suddenly without additional error code, just "Error creating bean with name....", will the bean being created again under some situation?